# django HttpResponseForbidden not working

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm excepting this code at is_send_permitted_interceptor if true to stop processing and redirect to forbidden. However, it does not, instead it returns the HttpResponseForbidden object in the function.

How do I actually get HttpResponseForbidden() to run in this context.

```
@login_required
def process_all(request):
    #If we had a POST then get the request post values.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        batches = Batch.objects.for_user_pending(request.user)

        # Will redirect/cancel request if user does not meet requirements, funds, permissions etc
        is_send_permitted_interceptor(request)
        # stuff here if everything is ok


def is_send_permitted_interceptor(request):
    # Check user has required credits in account to these batches.
    balance = Account.objects.get(user=request.user).get_balance()
    cost_of_sending = Batch.objects.batches_cost_pending(user=request.user)
    if balance < cost_of_sending:

        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: You may try to raise `PermissionDenied` instead. Your code as it stands doesn't return from the `process_all()` view if the condition `balance` fails...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't return the output of the "interceptor" in the `process_all` view, so it never reaches the user.

Just implement your logic in the interceptor, but only `return` from the main view, if needed.

```
def is_send_permitted(request):
    # Check user has required credits in account to these batches.
    balance = Account.objects.get(user=request.user).get_balance()
    cost_of_sending = Batch.objects.batches_cost_pending(user=request.user)
    if balance < cost_of_sending:
        return False
    else:
        return True


@login_required
def process_all(request):
    #If we had a POST then get the request post values.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        batches = Batch.objects.for_user_pending(request)

        # Will redirect/cancel request if user does not meet requirements, funds, permissions etc
        if not is_send_permitted_interceptor(request):
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        # stuff here if everything is ok
```

---

You could also raise an Exception here:

```
from django.core.exceptions import PermissionDenied
raise PermissionDenied()
```

But it's bad practice to raise exceptions when there is nothing truly exceptional going on.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `return` in the caller, because your check function is going to return to the caller, and its value is what you want to return to the browser.

A better approach would be the following:

```
def is_send_permitted_interceptor(user):
    # Check user has required credits in account to these batches.
    balance = Account.objects.get(user=user).get_balance()
    cost_of_sending = Batch.objects.batches_cost_pending(user=user)
    return balance < cost_of_sending
```

Then in your caller:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    batches = Batch.objects.for_user_pending(request.user)

    if is_send_permitted_interceptor(request.user):
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

This way its the view method is where all the redirects happen; and you avoid having to pass around `request`.

Comment: This will effectively `return None` if the operation is permitted.

Comment: Yes, which is why the second approach is recommended.