# How to use HttpResponseForbidden in this case?

Tags: python, django, django-views

This is a part of my code:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    if self.request.user.links.filter(pk=self.kwargs['pk']).exists():
        return super(View, self).get_queryset()
    else:
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

I want to check if user visits his or her link and if not return HttpResponseForbidden.
My code works nice with `raise PermissionDenied` but as I have read it's bad practice.

How to make my view work with `HttpResponseForbidden`?

**EDIT**:
If I use HttpResponseForbidden() I catch `'HttpResponseForbidden' object has no attribute 'filter'`

Comment: "I have read it's bad practice" - where? why? That's exactly what it's for.

Comment: @DanielRoseman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574151/django-httpresponseforbidden-not-working

Comment: You are returning, not raising, `HttpResponseForbidden` from the `get_queryset` function. And then somewhere you are probably trying to filter the `get_queryset` results, which are then expected to be a `QuerySet` instance but is in fact a `HttpResponseForbidden` instance.

Comment: @Charl ahhh, I understand, I am returning it as a query, that's why raising works, do you have any ideas where and how can I organize this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do all permission checks in the dispatch method.

Probably you already override them to decorate with login_required, so it's not worse to continue permission checks in the same place.

```
@login_required
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if not request.user.links.filter(pk=kwargs.get('pk', None)).exists():
        return HttpResponseForbidden()
    return super(View, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```